# PHP - Can upload without <form> tag?

Tags: php

If upload  file with php , with simple way , i can do like this page

```
<?php 
  if($_FILES)
{
   DO UPLOAD 
}
?>
<form action='' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post'>
  <input type="file" name="file">
  <input type="submit" name="upload" value="submit">
</form>
```

And now, i have to upload file but with out `<form>` tag like this

```
------index.html----
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <a href="upload.php">Upload</a>
--------------------

------upload.php-----
 CODE PHP TO UPLOAD FILE
---------------------
```

when click upload link , it can be a page that do upload.

But i don't know how to the upload  page can get file without tag form

Simple index.html only to send file name , and where it local to upload page proccess

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear what you want. But there is in fact a way to upload files without forms (and its POST request method/ctype). It's called a "PUT" request. All major http libraries can do that. Major browsers only via AJAX.

However, the receiving script must have specific support for it. Needs to check $_SERVER[REQUEST_METHOD] and read form php://input, and it really just allowed receiving a single file. It might even be necessary to set it up as Apache handler:

First Google result: http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/features.file-upload.put-method.php

Comment: But how does the Ajax request get access to the source file that is to be uploaded? I'm having a hard time imagining this working

Comment: @Pekka HTML5 drag and drop + file api for one. But IIRC you could also read an <input file> once it was selected. But anyway, XMLHttpRequest accepts PUT as transfer method.

Comment: nope, access to local files is categorically denied to Javascript, selected or not. That will change in HTML 5 but until then, you need a workaround like the jQuery Forms plugin uses (iframes).

Answer (score 0):

No. Onlywith help o multipart/orm-data form you can send $_FILES array for upload.

Comment: if page upload have form upload . And i use javascript  get path of file upload form index.html to input file browser in upload.php then do upload

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to do a standard file upload without a `<form>` tag.

The only exception would be a jQuery / Javascript workaround.

Comment: if index page only to store path of file. And i get this path to upload page by javascript then do upload .

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you want is a submit button that looks like a link. You probably want something like (HTML):

```
<form action="upload.php" type="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <button type="submit" class=="upload-submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

And (CSS):

```
button.upload-submit {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    color: #00f; /* Your link color here */
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: @Chameron, what do you need? It's unclear. You want to upload a file, and you want the upload file to be an `<a>` tag. Either you want an upload submit button that looks like a link, or you haven't been clear what you want.

Comment: i have index page with only 2 tag which you can see above. And <a> tag is a link to upload page. Upload page have to get path of file in index page and do upload. not css :(

Comment: @Chameron, can you edit the HTML? If you can't edit the HTML, what can you edit?

Comment: i can not edit the html :( my solution is use javascript to get information of file and send to upload page but i can't do it